# Nodejs Accepting connection blocks a main process

Tags: node.js, multithreading, http

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(req, res)
{
    console.log("Connected");
}).listen(80);
```

it is very simple spinet of code that doesn't work as it is spoused to. when i connect 3 clients at the same time it should print Connected 3 times. well it simply doesnt, it prints it once then waits for a connection time out, then accepts another one. Where is non blocking stuff that node promised or i am doing smth wrong ?

PS. it worked as it should before. no idea what happened.

Comment: You are not returning a response to client, so it will give a timeout. Inside your callback, put something like `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.setHeader('X-Foo', 'bar');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('ok');`

Answer (score 0):

For those who test your nodejs application with browser. Firefox doesn't allow multiple connections to same host/path while previous one wasnt closed.

GET / HTTP/1.1
GET /1 HTTP/1.1

with this scenario all works fine. if u like to test non blocking accepting and stuff use CURL or smth else.